# What is the name of the Master Stencil used by the Organization Chart Wizard in Visio?

Tags: visio

I've looked everywhere to see what the Master Stencil is called that the Organization Chart Wizard uses, in order to reference it in some VBA but I can't find it anywhere. Anyone know what it's called?

Answer (score 1):

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\OfficeXX\visio content\1033\ORGBLT_M.vssx

and there are others as well.